# Getting unknown property: app\models\ Yii2

Tags: php, yii

I don't know why I'm getting this error it says:

> Unknown Property – yii\base\UnknownPropertyException

Getting unknown property: `app\models\Servicerequest::Request_No`

It is so weird because I don't have Request_No in the `app\models\Servicerequest`, I don't have any ideas how to fix this if you guys have I'd appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Check your `Servicerequest` model. Maybe there is `request_no` field mentioned in the `rules()` method or something.

Comment: I already told that I don't have Request_No in the app\models\Servicerequest thats why its so weird lol

Comment: Update your question with `Servicerequest` model's code.

Comment: Check where you use this service as well, just search for Request_No in your code.

Comment: Thank you guys for your helps but it is so frustrating I don't know why it happened I checked all php files, good thing tho I have a backup so it works fine for now.

Comment: update your question and add  the code that produce this request .. (you should have a trace of the various levels of the called  code)

Comment: I stumbled across this answer because I had the same problem.  In my rule I had some whitespace after my attribute, once I removed the white space, it worked!